# Expand collapse text with html

Tags: javascript, html, css, expand

I would like to expand /collapse a text. I found several codes for that, but the issue they are using separates files for that .html 
What I need is to have all of them set in the same doc, .html
Because I'm using a HTML editor, so I'm obliged to have all the code in the same page.
Please advise what to do or if there is a tutorial that would be very helpful.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: just insert js code inside <script></script> and css inside <style></style>

Comment: the only advice is : read a Tutorial about HTML/CSS ... you will find this at the beginning of any tutorial. 5 min search and you have what you want

Comment: thank you, yes this is what I did inserted <script> .. but it was deleted. Is it possible to do it with pure HTML. I edited the Q.

Comment: `Is it possible to do it with pure HTML` : no ... HTML is not JS and JS is not HTML. JS must go inside script tag

Comment: yes, I cannot use JS in my editor, only css and HTML .Is that possible ?Q yes or no I did not ask for a code, I asked for a tutorial or an advise

Comment: asking for code, tutorial, advices are all off topic ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go study this and you will understand the basics:

[W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/)

Edit your code with this(there is allot more than just brackets):

[Brackets](http://brackets.io/)

This is one page HTML with `style` tag and `script` tag:

Your `css` would go into the `<style></style>`

Your `js` would go into the `<script></script>`

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html/js; charset=utf-8" />

<title>Untitled Document</title>
    
<style>

.page-header {
  color: #000;
}

#click {
  border-radius: 2%;
  height: 30px;
  color: green;
}
     
</style>

</head>

<body class="test">
    <header class="page-header">SIMPLE EXAmPLE</header>      
<div class="row">
  <div class="element">
      <div class="start" id="testdiv"></div>
      <button id="click">click to color background</button>
  </div>
</div>   
</body>
    
<script type="text/javascript">
    var clickAlert = document.getElementById('click');
    var rainbow = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"];

    function change() {
      document.body.style.background = rainbow[Math.floor(4*Math.random())];
    }

    clickAlert.addEventListener("click", change);  
</script>  
</html>
```

Comment: well, not sure if this question even deserve an answer. He's asking about the very basics of HTML/CSS and he need to at least to do some search. In 5min he can get what he want from any tutorial. Nothing against you, but answering such questions will encourage people to post this kind of question without doing any effort before. [my opinion by the way]

Comment: @TemaniAfif me and you meet again, i understand, i actually had this html on my desktop and decided to just go with it, but i agree with you without a doubt.

Comment: it is not about the code, my Q is I cannot insert <script> in my code, my editor only accepts css or html

Comment: then use another editor like brackets maybe? what editor are you using?

Comment: @victoria thing is editors like brackets and dreamweaver all accept js and css within html, even if it doesnt look like it, when you run the page in the browsers you wil see it works, depending if your script/html/css is valid.

Comment: @victoria updated my answer, where i did the google work for you.

Answer (score 9):

You can do this with pure HTML. Use  `<details>`

```html
<details>
    <summary> click me </summary>
    Text you want to expand or collide
</details>
```

Its that simple